# Spring JPA, @JointTable annotation not working

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-security

**What is wrong:** I'm trying to implement login using Spring Security. I'm using Spring Security's default endpoint `login`. I keep receiving 500s and I believe it's due to incorrect joint because when I'm printing

```
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    System.out.println("roles");
    System.out.println(roles);
    return roles;
}
```

roles is null. 'll show my stack trace at the end of the question.

**What I want to have:** correct working join.

**My code**
Join:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "userrole",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "iduser"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleid"))
private Set<Role> roles;
```

Whole Users model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_1")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "iduser")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="id_points")
    private Integer idPoints;
    @Column(name="username")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name="isblocked")
    private Boolean isBlocked;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="token")
    private String token;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "userrole",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "iduser"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleid"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(Users users) {
        this.id = users.getId();
        this.idPoints = users.getIdPoints();
        this.userName = users.getUserName();
        this.isBlocked = users.getBlocked();
        this.email = users.getEmail();
        this.lastName = users.getLastName();
        this.firstName = users.getFirstName();
        this.password = users.getPassword();
        this.token = users.getToken();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getIdPoints() {
        return idPoints;
    }

    public void setIdPoints(Integer idPoints) {
        this.idPoints = idPoints;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        System.out.println(userName);
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Boolean getBlocked() {
        return isBlocked;
    }

    public void setBlocked(Boolean blocked) {
        isBlocked = blocked;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        System.out.println("roles");
        System.out.println(roles);
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

CustomUsersDetails:

```
package com.shareabook.model;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CustomUserDetails extends Users implements UserDetails {
    public CustomUserDetails(final Users users) {
        super(users);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getRoles()
                .stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getRole()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return super.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return super.getUserName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Role model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "roleid")
    private Integer role_id;
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Integer getRole_id() {
        return role_id;
    }

    public void setRole_id(Integer role_id) {
        this.role_id = role_id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        System.out.println("role");
        System.out.println(role);
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

How I create database:

```
    CREATE TABLE Role (

                    roleId INTEGER NOT NULL,

                    role VARCHAR NOT NULL,

                    CONSTRAINT pkrole PRIMARY KEY (roleId)

    );





    CREATE SEQUENCE user_1_iduser_seq;



    CREATE TABLE User_1 (

                    idUser INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_1_iduser_seq'),

                    id_points INTEGER NOT NULL,

                    userName VARCHAR NOT NULL,

                    isBlocked BOOLEAN DEFAULT False NOT NULL,

                    email VARCHAR NOT NULL,

                    lastName VARCHAR NOT NULL,

                    firstName VARCHAR NOT NULL,

                    password VARCHAR NOT NULL,

                    token VARCHAR,

                    CONSTRAINT pkuser PRIMARY KEY (idUser)

    );





    ALTER SEQUENCE user_1_iduser_seq OWNED BY User_1.idUser;



    CREATE TABLE userRole (

                    idUser INTEGER NOT NULL,

                    roleId INTEGER NOT NULL

    );

ALTER TABLE userRole ADD CONSTRAINT role_userrole_fk

FOREIGN KEY (roleId)

REFERENCES Role (roleId)

ON DELETE NO ACTION

ON UPDATE NO ACTION

NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE User_1 ADD CONSTRAINT points_us_fk

FOREIGN KEY (id_points)

REFERENCES Points (idPoints)

ON DELETE CASCADE

ON UPDATE CASCADE

NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE userRole ADD CONSTRAINT user_1_userrole_fk

FOREIGN KEY (idUser)

REFERENCES User_1 (idUser)

ON DELETE NO ACTION

ON UPDATE NO ACTION

NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

How I populate databse with data:

```
INSERT INTO Role VALUES(1, 'ADMIN');
INSERT INTO Role VALUES(2, 'USER');
INSERT INTO Publisher VALUES(1, 'Zielona Sowa');
INSERT INTO Category VALUES(1,'kryminal');
INSERT INTO Points VALUES(1,20);
INSERT INTO Author VALUES(1, 'Tolkien', 'John Ronald Reuel');
INSERT INTO User_1 VALUES(1,1,'oliwka',false,'oliwka@wp.pl','m','o','jakies');

INSERT INTO userRole VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO Book VALUES(1,1,1,'Hobbit',null,3,false,1937);
INSERT INTO BooksByAuthors VALUES(1,1,1);
INSERT INTO BooksByCategory VALUES(1,1,1);
```

Stack trace:

```
Hibernate: select users0_.iduser as iduser1_1_, users0_.email as email2_1_, users0_.firstname as firstnam3_1_, users0_.id_points as id_point4_1_, users0_.isblocked as isblocke5_1_, users0_.lastname as lastname6_1_, users0_.password as password7_1_, users0_.token as token8_1_, users0_.username as username9_1_ from user_1 users0_ where users0_.username=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.iduser as iduser1_2_0_, roles0_.roleid as roleid2_2_0_, role1_.roleid as roleid1_0_1_, role1_.role as role2_0_1_ from userrole roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roleid=role1_.roleid where roles0_.iduser=?
oliwka
roles
null
2017-10-29 15:04:50.241 ERROR 11896 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.shareabook.model.CustomUserDetails.getAuthorities(CustomUserDetails.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.createSuccessAuthentication(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:225) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:197) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
```

Comment: You don't have any roles corresponding to that user in the database!

Comment: @AbdullahKhan, could please elaborate a bit? When creating the databse I have three tablse: user_1 (all user datas, name etc.), userRole (id of user and id of role) and role(id and role type).

Comment: What you are getting is a `NullPointerException` and thats because the user you are querying for in the database doesnt have any roles associated with it.Check your database and see if the user has proper roles.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan I edited my question and added script which I'm using for populating the databse. I might be mistaken but I the user should have role. I'm using an association table for that.

Comment: Got it! Just check if the user `oliwka` has any roles associated with it in the database.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan `oliwka` has  `iduser` = `1`. In userRole I have `iduser` = `1` and `roleid`=`1`. Also `role` has `roleid`=1 (which means it's an `ADMIN`)

Answer (score 0):

The association between `User` and `Role` is ***Many-to-Many*** and not ***One-to-many***.

Change your mappings like so in the `User` entity

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "iduser"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleid")
)
private Set<Role> roles;
```

Comment: Also please try to auto-generate your tables initially with `hbm2ddl` so that the tables and their mapping in the database map exactly to your Entities. Also check out the complete mapping [here](https://github.com/Abdullah8006/myapp-oracle/blob/master/src/main/java/com/appster/abdullah/entity/User.java).

Comment: I made this change and still have Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions, @AbdullahKhan?

Comment: Did you auto-generate the tables?? The only issue AFAIK is with the mappings now if you have now updated from onetomany to manytomany.

Comment: I'm using ```spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true```

Comment: Do you also have proper mappings in the Role entity?

Comment: Yes. I didn't manage to solve my issue. Used this approach instead: https://www.ashtpoint.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-login-example.html